# T-Sql ISNUMERIC('45D-1') returns 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, isnumeric

I have a T-Sql statement that is getting the next available number from a table.
but the column is of type nvarchar.
It dost have to be a number, But i still need to be able to get the next available number

so when i run the sql i try to only get numbers

```
WHERE
ISNUMERIC(myCol) AND CAST(REPLACE(myCol, N'0', N'') AS int)
```

but i get error

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '45D-1' to data type int.
```

So i ran just

```
select ISNUMERIC('45D-1')
```

And to my surprise its true

I already wrote a replace for "." which makes sense, But why is "D" a number? And why cant sql cast it? And is there a function to really test if its a Int?

Comment: That is because IsNumeric does not determine the value can be an integer. It returns 1 when the value can be implicitly cast to ANY datatype that is roughly like a number. If you are one 2012+ you could utilize try_convert. Here is a great article about the horrendous shortcomings of IsNumeric. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/

Comment: "Why is D a number?" Afaik SQL Server treats it interchangeably with E for some reason. `select cast('45D-1' as float)`. Looks like fortran uses D for that purpose.

Comment: In Fortran `E` notation indicates single-precision and `D` is double-precision. It's curious that SQL Server is happy with `select Cast( '45D-1' as Float )`, but fails on `select 45D-1`. (_Incorrect syntax near '-'._) (Ref [Table 6.4](http://www.cs.uwm.edu/~cs151/Bacon/Lecture/HTML/ch06s09.html).)

Answer (score 3):

`INT` and `NUMERIC` isn't the same. `ISNUMERIC` is returning anything that *could* possibly be a numeric type `(INT, BIGINT, DECIMAL, FLOAT, MONEY)`.

Example: `SELECT ISNUMERIC('$')`

This isn't an `INT` but returns true because it is something that is correctly formatted as `MONEY`. `ISNUMERIC` also works on scientific notations.... `SELECT ISNUMERIC('1e4')` would result to true. The point i'm making is don't trust `ISNUMERIC` out right without understanding what it is evaluating, or all the possibilities.

Comment: Could you please help me to understand, how/when 'D' is getting evaluated as numeric? Ex: select ISNUMERIC('4D1') returns 1

Comment: Scientific notation @Santhana. See *Examples and other notation* at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Answer (score 1):

If 2012+ you can use Try_Convert()

```
select Try_Convert(int,'45D-1')
```

Returns

```
NULL
```

Comment: i like your answer but its an old database (2008) and i get  'Try_Convert' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 1):

```
select ISNUMERIC('45D-1' + '.e0')
```

Worked for me and also helped me on the "." issue

Comment: @GordonLinoff Only you would consider that.  From this point on, I will need a DNA test proving that you are actually a human being.

Answer (score 1):

You hit by chance one valid notation (I did not know this either):

```
SELECT CAST('45D-1' AS FLOAT) --4.5
SELECT CAST('45D-2' AS FLOAT) --0.45
SELECT CAST('45D-3' AS FLOAT) --0.045
SELECT CAST('45D+1' AS FLOAT) --450
SELECT CAST('45D+3' AS FLOAT) --45000
```

Produces the same results as

```
SELECT CAST('45e-1' AS FLOAT)
SELECT CAST('45e-2' AS FLOAT)
SELECT CAST('45e-3' AS FLOAT)
SELECT CAST('45e+1' AS FLOAT)
SELECT CAST('45e+3' AS FLOAT)
```

Obviously there is a scientific notation using the letter `d` in the same way as the more usual `e`.

Just add `.0` to your string and `ISNUMERIC` will return *no number*

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(100)='45D-1';
SELECT ISNUMERIC(@s+'.0')
```

(Works only, if your numbers haven't got decimals already...)

### UPDATE

You might use `PATINDEX` to search for any occurance of a character not `0-9`:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(100)='45D-1';
SELECT CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@s)>0 THEN 'Nope!' ELSE 'Yeah!' END AS IsInt
```

Comment: Huh... it can't be that simple

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I just posted one more suggestion. Quite simple too...

Comment: I like the first option better... less typing.   Also I had no idea about the D notation.  Seriously, in all my years of working with very large and very small numbers, I've never seen it.

Comment: Just for fun, I tested the D notation in Excel and JavaScript.  It failed in both

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I just did some googling with `scientific notation d instead of e` and found a lot of results, all of them looking rather ancient :-)

Answer (score 0):

T-SQL works differently from other languages. Evaluation depends on query plan. It's free to evaluate them in any order that it sees as the most effective.

Use derivated qry like:

```
select * 
from (
    select * 
    from tbl
    where isnumeric(myCol) = 1
    -- where yourfunction(myCol) = 1 -- where your function returns null on non-numeric
) t
where myCol = 8
```

In your funtion you have to remove .#$A-Z,+-... But in some cases you want sciencist notation with D or E. Fastest is CRL function for this purposes.